# Getting a B matrix such that BxA = R (Row Reduced Echelon Form)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So, I had a 5x5 matrix (call it A) and I want to find a matrix B such that multiplying those give the row reduced echelon form of A. I have the row operations I did to get the RREF of A. So, is there any way to find such a matrix B such that BA = R?

Comment: In general, pre-multiplying affects rows, and post-multiplying affects columns. So in the product $\mathbf{AB}$, the matrix $\mathbf B$ is affecting the columns of $\mathbf A$. Are you sure you don't want the matrix $\mathbf B$ to go in front?

Comment: You are right, we have to find B such that BA = R. I'll be sure to edit the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TLDR**: Apply the exact same operations you applied to $\mathbf A$ to the identity matrix instead, and what you get will be your matrix $\mathbf B$.

---

#### Explanation

What makes EROs ([*elementary row operations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix)) special is that they correspond precisely to operations which can be carried out by premultiplying by a matrix. In other words, swapping two rows (for example) in matrix $\mathbf A$ is an ERO because it will result in $\mathbf{SA}$ where $\mathbf S$ is a special matrix which carries out this row-swap.

So how do we find this matrix $\mathbf S$, and more generally, how can we determine the matrices which carry out EROs?

Well, if we carry out a row-swap on the identity matrix $\mathbf I$, we should get $\mathbf{SI}$, but this will just equal $\mathbf S$.

More generally, if we carry out the row operations $\mathbf E_1, \dots, \mathbf E_n$ in order to a matrix $\mathbf A$, we will end up with the matrix $\mathbf E_n\cdots \mathbf E_1\mathbf A$ (note the order is reversed).

Thus the matrix that carries out these EROs is just $\mathbf B = \mathbf E_n\cdots \mathbf E_1$. You can find it by starting with the identity matrix, and carrying out the operations to it, since this will just be $\mathbf E_n\cdots \mathbf E_1\mathbf I = \mathbf E_n\cdots \mathbf E_1$.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You so much for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @Charles I hope it was eye-opening, it bothered me that when I first learned EROs I wasn't told _why_ they are special.

Comment: by Identity Matrix you mean the matrix with diagonals 1, and everything else 0, right?

Comment: @Charles Yes, since that leaves matrices unchanged.

Comment: @Charles You don't need to perform the operations in reverse.

The "reverse" thing comes from the following consideration: suppose you swap row 1 and row 2, call this operation $\mathbf E_1$, and suppose you do $R_2+3R_3\to R_3$, call this $\mathbf E_2$. The matrix $\mathbf B$ which carries out $\mathbf E_1$ and $\mathbf E_2$ in that order is the product of the matrices which carries them out separately: $\mathbf B = \mathbf E_2\mathbf E_1$. 

But if you're just going to apply the operations in order to the identity matrix,  just do it in the usual order. Does this help make things clear?

Comment: Here is a concrete example: https://docdro.id/M3bL1Fq. You do't really need to think about this reverse order thing to get the answer you're after, I just thought it's worth mentioning cause it's a common thing people get mixed up about.

Comment: It totally worked!!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got my concepts mixed up there again !! :)

Comment: @Charles Glad to be of help :)